# what have I done wrong parsing html with python urllib2 and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Trying to scrape some links from google, and learn python

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com.au/search?q=python')
html = response.read()
print html
response.close()
```

What have I done wrong? I get the following error?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d990999e71f4> in <module>()
      9 
     10 import urllib2
---> 11 response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com.au/search?q=python')
     12 html = response.read()
     13 print html

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in urlopen(url, data, timeout)
    124     if _opener is None:
    125         _opener = build_opener()
--> 126     return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    127 
    128 def install_opener(opener):

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    395         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    396             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 397             response = meth(req, response)
    398 
    399         return response

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in http_response(self, request, response)
    508         if not (200 <= code < 300):
    509             response = self.parent.error(
--> 510                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    511 
    512         return response

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in error(self, proto, *args)
    433         if http_err:
    434             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 435             return self._call_chain(*args)
    436 
    437 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    367             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
    368 
--> 369             result = func(*args)
    370             if result is not None:
    371                 return result

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    516 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    517     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 518         raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    519 
    520 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: Use the [google search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview), don't try to scrape google.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like google does not allow that type of requests

Try:[Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) or [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)

You can easily manipulate your request headers (user agent, etc..)
Check, which is easier and more appropriate for you

Comment: how about if I need to get the html from a page which is behind an intranet and requires authentication via username and password? can mechanise and or beautiful soup / urllib2 do that?

Comment: Sure. Read mechanize documentation. Or check out Requests. 
I create a script where login to some page, and there do something:

I will edit my post and put link of Requests

Comment: can you share the script to login, I have this, but It doesn't work for the page I want to scrape, maybe this one doesn't cope with httpS or something else is blocking it?

import urllib2

url = 'http://somesite'
username = 'usr'
password = 'pass'
p = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()

p.add_password(None, url, username, password)

handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(p)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
print page

Comment: i cant share all script, but this is good for start

`payload = {'Username':'myusername','Password':'mypassword'}`
`s = requests.session()`
`s.post(login_url,payload)`
for more please read docs of requests, because it is really simple :)

Comment: do you find it is better than mechanise an beautifulsoup?

I have used beautiful soup to parse links and strings, so im new to mechanise and requests, should I use BS for the links stuff or is it easy to use mech and requests - aka no need for beautifulsoup?